# Evaluation of $\int_{1}^{3}\left[\sqrt{1+(x-1)^3}+(x^2-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right]dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{3}\left[\sqrt{1+(x-1)^3}+(x^2-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right]dx$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Put $x-1 = t\;,$ Then $dx = dt$ and changing limits, We get

$$I = \int_{0}^{2}\left[\sqrt{1+t^3}+\left(t^2+2t\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right]dt$$

Now Let $\sqrt{1+t^3}=u+1\;,$ Then $t^3=(u+1)^2-1\Rightarrow t = \sqrt[3]{(u+1)^2-1}$

Now How Can I solve after that, Help me, Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's easier to split up the integral and deal with each part independently...

Comment: Why do you believe that this has an elementary way forward?  The integral $\int \sqrt{1+x^3}\,dx$ has no elementary primitive.

Comment: Where did you find this integral?

Comment: The whole trick is to notice that the two terms are $($almost$)$ [inverse functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions) to one another.

Comment: I agree with Lucian.  In a sense this is a question about the geometry of curves in the plane - the integral, which turns out to be 6, can actually be written as the area of a single rectangle.

Comment: Let $y = \sqrt{1+(x-1)^3}$, then $x = 1 + \sqrt[3]{y^2-1}$, 
the integral equals to

$$\int_1^3  y d \sqrt[3]{y^2-1} + \int_{1}^3 \sqrt[3]{x^2-1} dx
= \int_1^3 d(x \sqrt[3]{x^2-1}) = \left[x\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}\right]_1^3 = 6$$

Comment: Thanks Lucian, Michel, Achille hui.

Answer (score 3):

(Too long for a comment, I just post it here) Try with the substitution $(x-1)^3=(\sinh(t))^2$. Your integral gets converted into
$$
\int_0^{\sinh ^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt{2}\right)} \frac{(2 \cosh (t)) \left(\sqrt[3]{2 \sinh ^{\frac{2}{3}}(t)+\sinh ^{\frac{4}{3}}(t)}+\cosh (t)\right)}{3 \sqrt[3]{\sinh (t)}} \, dt\ .
$$
Quite amazingly, Mathematica now knows a primitive of the integrand (too long to be reported here) in terms of $\sinh$, $\cosh$ and hypergeometric $_2 F_1$. So the result given by Mathematica is 
$$
6+\left[\frac{3}{5} \left(\sqrt{3}+i\right) i \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3};\frac{3}{2};9\right)+\frac{6 \left(1+(-1)^{2/3}\right) \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{5 \Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{6}\right)}\right].
$$
Quite remarkably, the term in square brackets seems to be numerically very close to zero. Therefore your initial integral seems to be equal to $6$.